# not able to run manage.py runserver

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

Below is the problem i am facing while running the server.
I'm not able to start manage.py runserver . I'm Using sqlite3 database. I am trying to run quite basic application. system configurations: windows 10, python 2.7.

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.14393]
(c) 2016 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\rutwi_000>cd C:\Python27\Scripts\mysite

C:\Python27\Scripts\mysite>C:/Python27/python manage.py runserver
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 350, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 342, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 195, in fetch_command
    klass = load_command_class(app_name, subcommand)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 39, in load_command_class
    module = import_module('%s.management.commands.%s' % (app_name, name))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 16, in <module>
    from django.db.migrations.executor import MigrationExecutor
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 7, in <module>
    from .loader import MigrationLoader
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\loader.py", line 10, in <module>
    from django.db.migrations.recorder import MigrationRecorder
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\recorder.py", line 12, in <module>
    class MigrationRecorder(object):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\recorder.py", line 26, in MigrationRecorder
    class Migration(models.Model):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\recorder.py", line 27, in Migration
    app = models.CharField(max_length=255)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 1072, in __init__
    super(CharField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 166, in __init__
    self.db_tablespace = db_tablespace or settings.DEFAULT_INDEX_TABLESPACE
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 55, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 43, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 99, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "C:\Python27\Scripts\mysite\mysite\settings.py", line 15, in <module>
    django.setup()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 17, in setup
    configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 55, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 43, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 120, in __init__
    raise ImproperlyConfigured("The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.")
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.
```

Please help me with this question. Thanks!!!!!!

Below is the `settings.py` file.
**Note**: I do have a security key (not shown in the code below)

```
"""
Django settings for mysite project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 1.9.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/
"""

import os
import django
django.setup()

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = ''

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'personal',
    'blog',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',

]

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'mysite.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'mysite.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Comment: The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.

Comment: First check the secret key, add some string if empty on settings.py

Comment: Post your `settings.py`. We can't find the problem by simply looking at the error message.

Comment: Is there a virtual environment that you have created for this project? If yes did you execute runserver after activating the virtual environment?

Comment: I have added the settings.py file. Please have look on it and let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error traceback clearly states that your `SECRET_KEY` is empty

> raise ImproperlyConfigured("The SECRET_KEY setting must not be
>   empty.")
>       django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.

Generate a new one, you can use this

```
"""
Pseudo-random django secret key generator.
- Does print SECRET key to terminal which can be seen as unsafe.
"""
from __future__ import print_function
import string
import random


# Get ascii Characters numbers and punctuation (minus quote characters as they could terminate string).
chars = ''.join([string.ascii_letters, string.digits, string.punctuation]).replace('\'', '').replace('"', '').replace('\\', '')

SECRET_KEY = ''.join([random.SystemRandom().choice(chars) for i in range(50)])

print(SECRET_KEY)
```

save this in `secret_key.py` file, and do `python secret_key.py`, it will generate you a new `SECRET KEY`, then just copy new `SECRET_KEY` inside you're `settings.py` file.